# WPF: Cannot bind to a custom controls dependency property

Tags: dependency-properties

I've created a **custom control** with a dependency property for databinding.
The binded value should then be displayed in a **text box**.
This binding works properly.

The problem occurs when I implement my custom control. The grid's data context is a simple view model which contains a String property for binding.

1. If I bind this property to a standard wpf controls text box everything works fine.
2. If I bind the property to my custom control nothing happens.

After some debugging I found out that **SampleText** is searched in **CustomControl**. Of course it doesn't exist there.
Why is my property searched in **CustomControl** and not taken from the **DataContext** as it happens in scenario 1.

```xml
    <Window x:Class="SampleApplicatoin.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:SampleApplication"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.DataContext>
            <controls:ViewModel/>
        </Grid.DataContext>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding SampleText}"/>
        <controls:CustomControl TextBoxText="{Binding SampleText}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Below the **XAML** code of the custom control.
I use **DataContext = Self** to get the dependency property from code behind:

```xml
<UserControl x:Class="SampleApplication.CustomControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300" DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
    <Grid>
        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="87,133,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding TextBoxText}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

The xaml.cs file just contains the dependency property:

```cs
public partial class CustomControl : UserControl
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty TextBoxTextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("TextBoxText", typeof (String), typeof (CustomControl), new PropertyMetadata(default(String)));

        public CustomControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public String TextBoxText
        {
            get { return (String) GetValue(TextBoxTextProperty); }
            set { SetValue(TextBoxTextProperty, value); }
        }
    }
```

Thanks for any help on this. It really drives me crazy now.

**EDIT:**

I just came over two possible solutions:

Here the first (which works for me):

```xml
<!-- Give that child a name ... -->
<controls:ViewModel x:Name="viewModel"/>
<!-- ... and set it as ElementName -->
<controls:CustomControl TextBoxText="{Binding SampleText, ElementName=viewModel}"/>
```

The second one. This doesn't work in my case. I don't know why:

```xml
<controls:CustomControl TextBoxText="{Binding SampleText, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type controls:ViewModel}}}"/>
<!-- or -->
<controls:CustomControl TextBoxText="{Binding SampleText, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=controls:ViewModel}}"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar situation.
In my case, I fixed it with adding OnPropertyChanged in setter of property in ViewModel.